# How Do I Set This So That Certain Information Displays Whether Or Not The User Is Logged In?

Tags: php, authentication

I've been working on this code for a while. The website I'm building is not off-limit to those not logged in but shows different content depending on whether or not the user is logged in. For instance, if the user is logged in, it will display profile management links and others, but if the user is not logged in, it will simply show a link to either login or register.

I'm very fluent in HTML and CSS. I know a bit of PHP, but my skills in this area are limited as I'm trying to be more fluent in it.

Here is my log-in page. As you can see, I have user ids stored in my database as user_lister_id, so that's what I'm using to start a session. Here is the log-in page that I am using. I check to make sure that it can find the email and password in the database, in which case, upon success, it creates a session.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

    include("db_connect.php");


    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        //something was posted
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if(!empty($email) && !empty($password) && !is_numeric($email))
        {

            //read from database
            $query = "select * from users_listers where email = '$email' limit 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if($result)
            {
                if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {

                    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    
                    if($user_data['password'] === $password)
                    {

                        $_SESSION['user_lister_id'] = $user_data['user_lister_id'];
                        echo 'You have been successfully logged in!';
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                        echo 'window.location.href = "index.php"';
    
echo '</script>';
                        die;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            echo "wrong username or password!";
        }else
        {
            echo "wrong username or password!";
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <META name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/nav.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/blog.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/footer.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/forms.css" />
    <title</title>
   </head>
  <body>
  <?php require '../master-pages/header.php' ?>
    <section class="navigation">
        <?php require '../master-pages/nav.html' ?>
    </section>
    <section class="main-content">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <h1>Login</h1>
            
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
            
            <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
        </form>
        <div id="research-register-rules">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php require '../master-pages/footer.html' ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was getting an error by putting a header redirect after confirming the valid information, so decided to do a redirect using Javascript.

I am using a require_once to bring in the header.php page.
I was using a session_start(); at the top of the page, but an error said that a session had already been started, so I removed that.

This is my code for the header.php page, once again, to my understanding, it is checking to see if a session has been set under user_lister_id, which is should be after logging in. If a session is set, display account management links. If not, display options to register or login.

```
<?php
    require_once("db_connect.php");
    
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_lister_id'])) {
            echo '<section class="topnavbar">';
            echo '<div id="top-register">';
            echo '<a href="profile.php">Profile</a> / <a href="account-managment/account-settings.php">Account Settings</a> / <a href="case-requests">Case Requests</a> / <a href="http://www.paranormalsocieties.org/account-management/logout.php">Logout</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</section>';
        } else {
            echo '<section class="topnavbar">';
            echo '<div id="top-register">';
            echo '<a href="#"><a href="account-management/research-register.php">Lister Register</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="top-login">';
            echo '<a href="#"><a href="account-management/lister-login.php">Lister Login</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</section>';
        }
?>
            <section class="header-grid">
        <img src="../images/Logo.png" width="120" />
        <div id="ad-field">This content coming soon!</div>
</section>
```

I appreciate the help. Also, I am aware of security and SQL injections. This is not live yet, so after I get this working, I am going to add the security for protection against those.

Comment: what is the output of the session in header.php? check that with dump($_SESSION['user_lister_id']); if session created or not?

Comment: Using var_dump on the header.php page does nothing. I did create a separate page with just the var_dump code on it and it justs says NULL.

Comment: I tested your code, it's absolutely fine. I think the main problem is the session issue. first test session on your login page, define a custom value for it, and use session_status(); if the output is 2, it means the session is active. make sure $user_data['user_lister_id']; has a valid value.

Comment: I do know that the session is working on the login page because the special links work there, but not under the header page. I'm inputting the session_status(); on the header page, but it's saying it's not valid syntax in Dreamweaver. When I test the file, everything on the page, including the database connection goes away. Something appears to be wrong with that one line of code under the database connection in the last set of code that I provided. I have it pasted as this....session_status(): int;

Comment: Got the session_status to work. I got a result of 1, meaning for some reason a session is not getting set.